# django getting all objects from select

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

I also need the field (commentGroupDesc) from the foreign keys objects.

models.py

```
class commentGroup (models.Model):
    
        commentGroup = models.CharField(_("commentGroup"), primary_key=True, max_length=255)
        commentGroupDesc = models.CharField(_("commentGroupDesc"),null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.commentGroup)
        
        class Meta:
            ordering = ['commentGroup']
    
    class Comment (models.Model):
    
        commentID = models.AutoField(_("commentID"),primary_key=True)
        commentUser = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        commentGroup = models.ForeignKey(commentGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True)
        commentCI = models.ForeignKey(Servicenow, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True)
        commentText = RichTextField(_("commentText"), null=True, blank=True)
        commentTableUpdated = models.CharField(_("commentTableUpdated"), null=True, blank=True, max_length=25)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.commentGroup)
        
        class Meta:
            ordering = ['commentGroup']
```

views.py

```
comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=commentID)
```

Here I get the commentGroup fine but I also need commentGroupDesc to put into my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, it's not a good thing to name same your model field as model name which is `commentGroup` kindly change field name, and run migration commands.

You can simply use chaining to get `commentGroupDesc`, also it's better to use `get_object_or_404()` so:

```
comment = get_object_or_404(Comment,pk=commentID)

group_desc = comment.commentGroup.commentGroupDesc
```

Remember to change field and model name first.